# may i know why User Store Manager Class not show in wso2 identity server by installing wso2 identityserver using docker

Tags: devops, wso2-identity-server

Anybody please help me why 
custom User Store Manager Class not displaying in wso2 identity server installing  by docker (version 17.06.1).
 I placed my custom user store manger class jar file into wso2is/repository/components/dropins folder and I placed mysql-connector jar into  wso2is/repository/components/lib folder.

in general when I am running wso2server.sh file the server was running and the custom user store manager class will showed but by using docker  the server was running  but the custom user store manager class not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

There can be one of many reasons for this issue, including,

1) The bundle compiled with Java8 and docker run with Java 7

2) Docker image has not updated with the bundle having the UserStore.

Try putting an INFO log on the bindle activation and see if that is printed in the logs when you run with docker, to see if the bundle really gets activated.